# How to detect file descriptor leaks in Node

Tags: node.js

I suspect that I have a file descriptor leak in my Node application, but I'm not sure how to confirm this. Is there a simple way to detect file descriptor leaks in Node?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I have Node running on Ubuntu 13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Track open files

On linux you can use the `lsof` command to list the open files [for a process].

Get the PIDs of the thing you want to track:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Let's say its PID 1111 and 1234, list the open files:

```
lsof -p 1111,1234
```

You can save that list and compare when you expect them to be released by your app.

### Make it easier to reproduce

If it's taking a while to confirm this (because it takes a while to run out of descriptors) you can try to lower the limit for file descriptors available using `ulimit`

```
ulimit -n 500 #or whatever number makes sense for you
#now start your node app in this terminal
```